# Hostname changes in the terminal when connecting to some wifi networks

Tags: terminal

When I connect to some wifi networks my computer hostname changes in the terminal - is this normal? Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 11):

On Lion (at least), the best way to achieve this is by running [scutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/10.6/man8/scutil.8.html):

```
sudo scutil --set HostName NAME
```

replacing NAME with the hostname you want. Note that `/etc/hostconfig` is deprecated, if you can believe a comment at the top of the file.

Comment: This fix still works on Mavericks if anybody is interested. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: FWIW, `scutil` is still there on Big Sur. I expect it to be in Monterey too, but I haven't upgraded yet myself.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I'm on Monterey, and it still works.

Comment: Still works on Ventura, at least.

Answer (score 6):

OS X normally gets the hostname from a reverse lookup of the IP address the machine has. When you're on DHCP, that means your hostname can change. If you want to force a hostname, you can edit /etc/hostconfig (use the cli editor of your choice, you'll need to use sudo) and change **HOSTNAME=-AUTOMATIC**- to **HOSTNAME=NameYouWant**

Comment: When I did this, a lot of tools I use in the command line all broke...seems they stored the hostname. Is that common?

Comment: @ChrisAbrams: I don't think that's common, but it's hard to say more without knowing what broke, and how. (I know it's a long time since you asked. I saw this just now.)